# creating a window in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, window, android-asynctask

The application is to download some text from a server and display the text to users in a new window. I need a new window since the amount of text may be very large.

Since the downloading process may take too much time, I use an inner `AsyncTask` class to take care of it as a background task. After I download the text, I wish to create a new window in `onPostExecute()` in `AsyncTask` to display the task.

Code in `onPostExecute()` is as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.parent, DisplayActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("array", fileContent);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

`this.parent` refers to the Activity showing to the user at the time. file Content is the string containing the text.

However, the code does not work. No window shows. Any help is appreciated.

By the way, is there any better way to implement the application?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.parent, DisplayActivity.class);
```

Instead of `this.parent` you should use,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Name.this, DisplayActivity.class);
```

Comment: What do you mean by Activity_Name?? You mean the name of the class which contains the AsyncTask class? I use "this.parent" since I pass the Activity as a data member to AsyncTask. How can I make my code the same format as yours??

Comment: Its your Activity in which you are writing AsyncTask(Base Class)

Comment: sorry. I typed wrongly, so there was an error. When I type correctly, there is no new window showing up.

Comment: When the above code is executed, the andorid emulator says "unfortunately, Activity has stopped".